# Is $\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$ always a number different from zero?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ different from the null function. Is $\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx$ always a number different from zero? I believe it is, but I don't know how to prove it since I am new to integration.

Comment: Draw a graph, you could have an infinite number of functions such that integral of f from $0$ to $1$ is $0$, just need area of shaded region above and below axis to be equal, and then they cancel

Comment: what about $f(x)=x-1/2$ ?

Comment: The value of the integral is a weak constraint on a function. There are lots of examples.

Answer (score 4):

Take your favourite non-constant function $g$ for which $K:=\int_0^1 g(x)dx$ is finite. Then $f(x):=g(x)-K$ is a counterexample to your conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

How about the function $f=x-\frac12$? Then $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0.$

Answer (score 0):

No. The simplest is $f(x)=0$. Any function antisymmetric around $1/2$ is another example, such a $\cos(2\pi x)$

Comment: Isn't $f(x) = \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ symmetric around $x = \frac{1}{2}$? Maybe rephrase as symmetric to the point $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be antisymmetric